# Accessing objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use indexOf to find a key in an array that look like this

```
const areaCode = [
    {
        "area_code": 656,
        "city": "city1"
    },
    {
        "area_code": 220,
        "city": "city2"
    },
    {
        "area_code": 221,
        "city": "city3"
    }]
export default areaCode
```

Then I'm trying to get the city name based on the area_code number

```
const code = input
let found = indexOf(areaCode, ["area_code", code]);
const city = areaCode[found].city
```

But found comes as -1, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `code`?

Comment: its a valid area_code! like, 656 or 221 in the example above

Comment: Actually, `indexOf` doesn't use `iteratee` for the search - it does a SameValueZero comparison. Any particular reason to use it instead of just `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Lodash _.find function.

It'd be as this:

```
const areaCode = [
{
    "area_code": 656,
    "city": "city1"
},
{
    "area_code": 220,
    "city": "city2"
},
{
    "area_code": 221,
    "city": "city3"
}]
const code = input;
const found = _.find(areaCode, function(a){ return a.area_code == code });
console.log(found.city)
```

const found will hold the matching area.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find

Answer (score 0):

I believe `_.findIndex()` is what you need:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findIndex

```
let found = findIndex(areaCode, ["area_code", code]);
```

Here’s a demo https://jsbin.com/ruqayunini/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation [`_.indexOf`](https://lodash.com/docs/#indexOf) will perform a [SameValueZero](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) comparison to locate the index. In short, for `indexOf(data, item)` it will try to use `===` to compare `item` against every entry in `data`.

Instead you can use [`_.findIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs/#findIndex) which accepts the usual shorthand for [`_.matchesProperty`](https://lodash.com/docs/#matchesProperty) that will be accepted by [`_.iteratee`](https://lodash.com/docs/#iteratee):

```js
const { findIndex } = _;

const areaCode = [
    {
        "area_code": 656,
        "city": "city1"
    },
    {
        "area_code": 220,
        "city": "city2"
    },
    {
        "area_code": 221,
        "city": "city3"
    }]

const code = 220;

let found = findIndex(areaCode, ["area_code", code]);
console.log("index:", found);

const city = areaCode[found].city
console.log("city:", city);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Although, given your usage, you probably want [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/#find)

```js
const { find } = _;

const areaCode = [
    {
        "area_code": 656,
        "city": "city1"
    },
    {
        "area_code": 220,
        "city": "city2"
    },
    {
        "area_code": 221,
        "city": "city3"
    }]

const code = 220;

let found = find(areaCode, ["area_code", code]);
console.log("index:", found);

const city = found.city
console.log("city:", city);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```